# My API Get Request can get me no more than 100 , how to loop it so I can get all Items?

Tags: python, api, swagger

SO Im working to get all items from API using Python3, the problem that when I run the script it shows me only 100 ,, while I know they are more than 1000.

I tried to use while loop but failed with repeating the same results

```py
import requests
import json
def get_list_call(offset): 

    url = "https://link.com/monitoring/v1/switches"

    querystring = {"limit":"%s"%limit,"offset":"%s"% offset}
    headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer Token",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers,params=querystring)

    return(response.text)

result = get_list_call(0)
data_json = json.loads(result)
count = (data_json['count'])
print (count)
```

I see the results of 20 Items 
and count = 20

Comment: It doesn't look like you are appending your query string to the URL at any point before making the request?

Comment: Thanks ,,,I edited the question ,, the thing is every time I run it I get the same list which are 100 items (switches), thats why I name it (get_list_call) function to loop it and get more ,,,I end up with an infinite loop for the same list.

Comment: Look up the documentation for the API.  they may limit to a max of 100, then use some sort of paging capability to allow you to request the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for the comments, so I was able to use flag total in  the API, to show me the total of the items, then I used while loop to get them all.

Thanks